# enable https on swoole with laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ssl, swoole

hi i have problem enabling `https` on **swoole** with `laravel api` when i'm tryping to sending api request through ***http*** it works well but i can't through `https` :

curl http://127.0.0.1:8008/api/v1/search?include=searchplace

**it works**

curl https://127.0.0.1:8008/api/v1/search?include=searchplace

**not work**

hosting application on **apache2** ubuntu.

`php --ri swoole`

```
Swoole => enabled
Author => Swoole Team <team@swoole.com>
Version => 4.5.7
Built => Nov 11 2020 16:26:07
coroutine => enabled
epoll => enabled
eventfd => enabled
signalfd => enabled
cpu_affinity => enabled
spinlock => enabled
rwlock => enabled
openssl => OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
pcre => enabled
mutex_timedlock => enabled
pthread_barrier => enabled
futex => enabled
async_redis => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
swoole.enable_coroutine => On => On
swoole.enable_library => On => On
swoole.enable_preemptive_scheduler => Off => Off
swoole.display_errors => On => On
swoole.use_shortname => On => On
swoole.unixsock_buffer_size => 8388608 => 8388608
```

i need help to be able to enable our app api requests through `https` with **swoole**

swoole configuration file :

```
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP server configurations.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | @see https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-server/configuration
    |
    */
    'server' => [
        'host' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_PORT', '1215'),
        'public_path' => base_path('public'),
        // Determine if to use swoole to respond request for static files
        'handle_static_files' => env('SWOOLE_HANDLE_STATIC', true),
        'access_log' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_ACCESS_LOG', false),
        // You must add --enable-openssl while compiling Swoole
        // Put `SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP | SWOOLE_SSL` if you want to enable SSL
        'socket_type' => SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP | SWOOLE_SSL,
        'process_type' => SWOOLE_PROCESS,
        'options' => [
            'pid_file' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_PID_FILE', base_path('storage/logs/swoole_http.pid')),
            'log_file' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_LOG_FILE', base_path('storage/logs/swoole_http.log')),
            'daemonize' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_DAEMONIZE', false),
            // Normally this value should be 1~4 times larger according to your cpu cores.
            'reactor_num' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_REACTOR_NUM', swoole_cpu_num()),
            'worker_num' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_WORKER_NUM', swoole_cpu_num()),
            'task_worker_num' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_TASK_WORKER_NUM', swoole_cpu_num()),
            // The data to receive can't be larger than buffer_output_size.
            'package_max_length' => 20 * 1024 * 1024,
            // The data to send can't be larger than buffer_output_size.
            'buffer_output_size' => 10 * 1024 * 1024,
            // Max buffer size for socket connections
            'socket_buffer_size' => 128 * 1024 * 1024,
            // Worker will restart after processing this number of requests
            'max_request' => 3000,
                                                     
           // Enable coroutine send
            'send_yield' => true,
            // You must add --enable-openssl while compiling Swoole
            'ssl_cert_file' => '/etc/apache2/something.crt',
            'ssl_key_file' => '/var/www/something.com.key',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable to turn on websocket server.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'websocket' => [
        'enabled' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_WEBSOCKET', false),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Hot reload configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'hot_reload' => [
        'enabled' => env('SWOOLE_HOT_RELOAD_ENABLE', false),
        'recursively' => env('SWOOLE_HOT_RELOAD_RECURSIVELY', true),
        'directory' => env('SWOOLE_HOT_RELOAD_DIRECTORY', base_path()),
        'log' => env('SWOOLE_HOT_RELOAD_LOG', true),
        'filter' => env('SWOOLE_HOT_RELOAD_FILTER', '.php'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Console output will be transferred to response content if enabled.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'ob_output' => env('SWOOLE_OB_OUTPUT', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pre-resolved instances here will be resolved when sandbox created.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'pre_resolved' => [
        'view', 'files', 'session', 'session.store', 'routes',
        'db', 'db.factory', 'cache', 'cache.store', 'config', 'cookie',
        'encrypter', 'hash', 'router', 'translator', 'url', 'log',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Instances here will be cleared on every request.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'instances' => [
        //
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Providers here will be registered on every request.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'providers' => [
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
                                                                  
],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetters for sandbox app.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'resetters' => [
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\ResetConfig::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\ResetSession::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\ResetCookie::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\ClearInstances::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\BindRequest::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\RebindKernelContainer::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\RebindRouterContainer::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\RebindViewContainer::class,
        SwooleTW\Http\Server\Resetters\ResetProviders::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Define your swoole tables here.
    |
    | @see https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'tables' => [
        // 'table_name' => [
        //     'size' => 1024,
        //     'columns' => [
        //         ['name' => 'column_name', 'type' => Table::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 1024],
        //     ]
        // ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Https only works with fully qualified domain names and not ip addresses. However I see you are using a localhost ip address and probably forwarding requests from apache to swoole and in that case you really dont need https when connecting internally. You only need https on the public facing apache

Comment: I did it and forwarded the public to private ip the same result not working .

Comment: are you forwarding to https://127.0.0.1:8008 or http://127.0.0.1:8008
also try loading static files on apache with https directly so you know the apache side works.

Comment: yes i added the security group and port forwarded port 8008 and in apache i added the crts and keys and works well

Comment: if you are forwarding internally to non https then i'm not really sure why it doesnt work. on my end swoole works just fine behind apache, nginx or exposed directly to the public internet

Comment: could you please give me the configuration for https to be able to listening for 443 on apache configuration to able to work with swool ? thanks

Comment: <VirtualHost *>
    ServerName **removed**

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

also be sure to daemonize the swoole http server. could i take a look at your swoole and apache configs

Comment: thanks for your config file but there are errors with these apache configurations could you please add your code more clarified in your answer ? thanks

Comment: i added the  `swoole_http.php` config file to the question

Comment: any help please till now i couldn't find any solution .

Comment: any help please ?